# Class object cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have name of my model class(POJO) in a string var and I create it's class object as follows:

```
String modelName = "ModelA";
```

`Class modelNameClass = Class.forName(modelName );`

Where ModelA is name of model class.
In next line a generic method (getGenericRecord) is returning data for ModelA. 
Now I am getting 'modelNameClass cannot be resolved to a type', error while doing the following:

```
modelNameClass listOfOfflineRecords = (modelNameClass) dbConn.getGenericRecord
```

Please correct me if I am making a mistake.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`modelNameClass` is a variable of type `Class` declared and initialized here

```
Class modelNameClass = Class.forName(modelName );
```

A cast expression and a variable declaration expects the name of a type, not a variable name. The following

```
modelNameClass listOfOfflineRecords = (modelNameClass) dbConn.getGenericRecord
// ^ wrong, should be a type name        ^ wrong, should be a type name
```

is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: I knew it's syntactically incorrect. I was just trying to explain my expectations. Sorry for confusing you. As I said, getGenericRecord() may return the records for any model class e.g. ModelA, ModelB etc. Good thing is I have the name of that model class in a string var. Now next question is how to get results of getGenericRecord() in listOfOfflineRecords  or What should be type of listOfOfflineRecords ?

Comment: @love You'll need a common type known at compile time. Maybe a common interface.

Comment: How about instead of returning generic type, I return Object of resultSet from getGenericRecord() method. Then I can cast this Object into any model as I wish. e.g. `Object TempX = dbConn.getGenericRecord();` `ModelA expectedModel = (ModelA) TempX;`

Comment: @LoveForDroid Yes, that's fine if you know `ModelA` at compile time.